# Finding the closest character string in a second data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a quite big `data.frame` with non updated names and I want to get the correct names that are stored in another  `data.frame`.
I am using `stringdist` function to find the closest match between the two columns and then I want to put the new names in the original `data.frame`.

I am using a code based on `sapply` function, as in the following example :

```
dat1 <- data.frame("name" = paste0("abc", seq(1:5)),
          "value" = round(rnorm(5), 1))


dat2 <- data.frame("name" = paste0("abd", seq(1:5)),
                   "other_info" = seq(11:15))

dat1$name2 <- sapply(dat1$name,
                        function(x){
                          char_min <- stringdist::stringdist(x, dat2$name)
                          dat2[which.min(char_min), "name"]
                        })
dat1
```

However, this code is too slow considering the size of my `data.frame`.

Is there a more optimized alternative solution, using for example `data.table` R package?

Comment: As a first step, you can use `unlist(lapply)` rather than `sapply` to speed up your code.

Comment: Try `RecordLinkage::levenshteinDist` instead `stringdist::stringdist` - 3x faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the data frames into data tables:

```
dat1 <- data.table(dat1)
dat2 <- data.table(dat2)
```

Then use the ":=" and "amatch" command to create a new column that approximately matches the two names:

```
dat1[,name2 := dat2[stringdist::amatch(name, dat2$name)]$name]
```

This should be much faster than the sapply function. Hope this helps!

Comment: Just using `amatch` gives pretty good performance. Converting to `data.table` produces only a small additional speedup.

Comment: Excellent, it works in a very performant way (in terms of memory and speed).

Comment: @P.Denelle Great!